# What bits of memory are moved into an 8 bit register?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Say we have a base address (in this instance: esi+ecx), and we point to it to store some 16 bit piece of information and then we do this:

```
mov bl, byte [ds:esi+ecx]
```

Are moving the first 8 bits of that memory into that 8 bit register?

Comment: Yes, it loads the lower part of the 16 bit value using the little endian system.

Comment: You are loading one byte starting at the specified address.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean the question, let we have the following code (FASM format):

```
var1  db     0
var2  db     0

      mov    word [var1], 1234h

; here [var1]==34h; [var2] = 12h

      mov    bl, [var1]
```

; here bl == 34h;

The above behavior is valid for any addressing mode, i.e. regardless of the way the address is specified in the instruction. Notice, that the addresses in x86 architecture **always** point to a memory byte.